# Cloud 9 compiling c++98, need c++11

Tags: c++, terminal, cloud9-ide

I am attempting to compile a program that uses ranged based for loops, and a couple other features available only in c++11 and above. When I attempt to compile the program using a makefile in the terminal, I get this error:

```
error: range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
```

and some warnings:

```
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 [enabled by default]
```

What's annoying is that this has happened before, but it just resolved itself. However, this time it has not resolved itself.

Here's my makefile:

```
main: main.o
    g++5 -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -g *.cpp -o lab4
```

Here are some examples of things I have tried to change in the makefile, but did not work.

```
g++-5 -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -g *.cpp -o lab4
g++5 -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Werror -g *.cpp -o lab4
g++5 -std=c++0x -Wall -Werror -g *.cpp -o lab4
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Werror -g *.cpp -o lab4
g++ -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Werror -g *.cpp -o lab4
```

All of the previous examples result in similar warnings and errors. What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: What compiler version are you using? Are you sure it supports C++11?

Comment: Your makefile provides linking instructions for linking `main.o` into `main`. The `-std=c++11` option for linking is not going to accomplish anything. That horse has left the barn already. You need to provide a Makefile rule for ***compiling*** `main.cpp` into `main.o`, that specifies this option. Change the rule to specify `main: main.cpp`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I asked tons of people at my university and none of them had any idea. I feel kind of unintelligent for missing that, but thanks again!

Comment: @David _"I feel kind of unintelligent for missing that"_ Well, no need to do so. "You'll always find your keys where you searched them in the obvious last place. _- Aristotle -_" ;-)